# Indexing one to many relational structure in solr

Tags: indexing, solr

I have a schema like the following that I want to index in SOLR. But I am not sure how to manage the one to many relationship between the first table: users and second table: address

```
ID      NAME      DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------
1       NAME1     DEMO DESCRIPTION ONE
2       NAME2     DEMO DESCRIPTION TWO
3       NAME3     DEMO DESCRIPTION THREE

-------------------------------------------------
ADDR_ID   USER_ID  CITY     STATE     COUNTRY
-------------------------------------------------
1         1        cityv    statev    countryv
2         1        cityw    statew    countryw
3         2        cityx    statex    countryx
4         2        cityy    statey    countryy
5         3        cityz    statez    countryz
```

How to index users with multiple addresses?
Also how to search them by either users.name, address.city / address.state name?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Block Join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers) with parent/child structure